# When does construing $M$ as a simultaneous mediator and moderator of a variable's effect make sense?

Tags: regression, interaction, mediation

Hayes (2018) p. 540 writes

> I will not take a firm position on whether construing $M$ as a
> simultaneous mediator and moderator of a variable’s effect could ever
> make substantive or theoretical sense. I am uncomfortable
> categorically ruling out the possibility that $M$ could be a moderator
> just because it is correlated with $X$. My guess is that there are many
> real-life processes in which things caused by $X$ also influence the
> size of the effect of $X$ on $Y$ measured well after $X$. But $M$ would have
> to be causally prior to $Y$ in order for this to be possible, implying
> that $M$ could also be construed as a mediator if $M$ is caused in part by
> $X$ but also influences $Y$ in some fashion.

Hayes is referring to a situation like the one depicted on p. 539, i.e. a conditional process model in which $X$ moderates its own indirect effect. The top diagram he describes as conceptual and the bottom one as statistical.

[image: Conceptual and Statistical diagram of conditional process model]

The model would translate into the following equations

$M = i_M = a_X + e_M$

$Y = i_Y + c'_1X + bM + c'_2XM + e_Y$

It follows that the direct effect of $X$ in this model would not be $c'_1$ but rather $c'_1 + c'_2M$. So long as $c'_2M \neq 0$, $M$ moderates $X$'s direct effect on $Y$.

Unlike [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/218401/testing-mediation-and-moderation-can-one-variable-function-as-both-mediator-and) question, I am not asking whether it can be done mathematically - I am aware that it can. Instead, I am asking: under what circumstances it will be sensible theoretically/substantively interpretable? Also, why has this question proved a controversial one in the mediation literature?

Hayes, A. F. (2018). Introduction to mediation, moderation, and conditional process analysis: A regression-based approach. Guilford publications.