# Moderation (interaction) - Cannot use moderation if a moderator has an effect on independent variable?

Tags: multiple-regression, econometrics, interaction, endogeneity

I have a following simple moderation model:

$$ y = b_0 + b_1x + b_2m + b_3(x \times m) + e $$

However, previous studies have also found that $x$ has a effect on $m$:

$$ m = a_0 + a_1x + u $$

If $x$ has an effect on $m$, will $b_3$ be confounded with $a_1$? In other words, would $b_3$ include $a_1$, and thus, I cannot use the moderation model?

Thank you in advance for your advices!

Comment: Dear Thomas Bilach, Thank you for your edits (and my apology for not being familiar with the format. I will keep the formatting next time!)

Comment: No need to apologize. It is a good question (+1).

Answer (score 1):

In moderation, it is not an assumption that the main terms $x$ and $w$ to be uncorrelated. For instance, there are many methodological papers (e.g. [this paper](https://bpspsychub.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.2044-8317.2010.02002.x)) on multicollinearity in moderation analysis, which (a) are concerned by very high correlations between main effects and (b) show that it is not an issue [see this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.3758/s13428-016-0785-2).

My own works show that it even has a positive effect (soon to be published - sorry for the self promotion).

So, yes, you can une the moderator even if it is correlated.

I would simply advise to check the estimates and see if they make sense (which you should do anyway). Interpreting the interaction will help a lot also.

Comment: Dear POC, Thank you very much for your detailed answer! Your answer really helped me understand the issue deeper. I believe the issues with multicollinearity can be applied to my issue (where =0+1+)?? I was just a bit concerned because multicollinearity sounds more like correlation, but my issue is rather causality (at least previous studies argued so).,,

Comment: If you consider adding a mediator (is it what you meant by a causal effect?), thus a mediator as moderator (see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/472239/when-does-construing-m-as-a-simultaneous-mediator-and-moderator-of-a-variable), then it is slightly different, because of the best way to model the data. If the model is justified there should be no statistical problem, even though some may be see some conceptual problems (partial snawer to the post linked).

Comment: Dear POC. Thank you for your prompt and detailed response! Sorry for the confusion. What I meant by causality is not the mediation. I wanted to double check whether I can cite "high multicollinearity between  and  isn't a concern for the interaction term" for my issue. To me, multicollinearity sounds more like correlation between  and . However, previous studies found that  has a causal effect on (not just correlated with)  (=0+1+). My apology for the ignorance. Thank you again for your invaluable help!

Comment: Basically, you can use SEM and add the path $m$ on $x$, but you are not forced to.